# Colorama won't stop printing colored text

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, colorama

I have been experiencing a printing problem regarding my Fores in colorama, Visual Studio Code, Python. The Fores (Fore.GREEN) prints GREEN in every single part of code I print out, including the parts where I don't want it to show up. Here´s my code and the output of the code:

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore
colorama.init()



print("let´s play!")


answer = input("What does CPU stand for?: ")

if answer == "Central Processing Unit":
    print(Fore.GREEN + "Correct")
else: 
    print(Fore.RED + "Incorrect, game will now crash")
    quit()


answer = input("What does RAM stand for?: ")

if answer == "Random Access Memory":
    print(Fore.GREEN + "Correct")
else: 
    print(Fore.RED + "Incorrect, game will now crash")
    quit()


answer = input("What does USB stand for?: ")

if answer == "Universal Serial Bus":
    print(Fore.GREEN + "Correct")
else: 
    print(Fore.RED + "Incorrect, game will now crash")
    quit()


print(Fore.GREEN + "Congratulations, you survived the game and won")
```

```
OUTPUT: 
let´s play!
What does CPU stand for?: Central Processing Unit
Correct (GREEN)
What does RAM stand for?: Random Access Memory (GREEN)
Correct (GREEN)
What does USB stand for?: Universal Serial Bus (GREEN)
Correct (GREEN)
```

As you can see the GREEN follows everything I print out from the first "Correct". I only want the GREEN show up when printing Correct, as you can see I have written "print(Fore.GREEN + "Correct")" on every "Correct". However, I don´t want the GREEN to show up in my questions as it does, from my first "print(Fore.GREEN + "Correct")" the GREEN keeps showing up on everything I print.

Is there any fix for this? How do I make the GREEN (Fore.GREEN) stop in my printing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset color using `Fore.RESET` after every text or you can set `autoreset=True` inside init function.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
print(Fore.GREEN + "Correct" + Fore.WHITE)
```

or `+ Fore.YOUR_TERMINAL_TEXT_COLOR`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `colorama.Style.RESET_ALL` to return to the default settings.

See an example here:
https://github.com/tartley/colorama#usage

This should work even if you don't use white as your default foreground colour.

Answer (score 0):

Use ***Fore.RESET*** at the end of the string:

```
from colorama import Fore

print(Fore.BLUE + "Hello, World!" + Fore.RESET)
```